# Bitvise ssh Store encrypted password in profile

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect to a server from bitvise ssh client. I have selected Hostname and port 22. I have the password to droplet from digitalocean. I am logging in first time it is asking password which I dont know. I have selected initial method as password with store encrypted password in profile. where is the profile password saved